# Java TCP - server & client working, but can't get answer

Tags: java, tcp

I'm trying to make a small TCP server/client thingy. I have a client and a server, and after getting some basic Exceptions solved, nothing works.
The client is supposed to send (user) data to the server (at port 6789, localhost), who is then supposed to write it in uppercase and end it back. Everything seems to work, except for sending back the uppercase. Here is the code:

TCPServer:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("SERVER");

        String clientSentence;
        String capitalizedSentence;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(6789);


        TCPClient.main(null);


        while (true) {
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            System.out.println("<S> Connection!");
            BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()) );
            DataOutputStream toClient = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            clientSentence = fromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("<S> Recieved: " + clientSentence);

            capitalizedSentence = clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
            System.out.print("About to send: " + capitalizedSentence);
            toClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
        }
    }

}
```

TCPClient:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("CLIENT");

        String sentence;
        String modSentence;
        BufferedReader inUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket clientToServer = new Socket("localhost", 6789);
        DataOutputStream outServer = new DataOutputStream(clientToServer.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inServer = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientToServer.getInputStream()) );

        System.out.println("<C> Type now: ");
        sentence = inUser.readLine();
        System.out.println("<C> Got it!");

        System.out.println("<C> Sending " + sentence + " to server...");
        outServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        outServer.flush();

        System.out.println("<C> Server respodse:");
        modSentence = inServer.readLine();

        System.out.println("<C> From server: " + modSentence);
        clientToServer.close();
    }
}
```

Console:

```
SERVER
CLIENT
<C> Type now: 
efd
<C> Got it!
<C> Sending efd to server...
<C> Server respodse:
asd
```

and...

Nothing

Comment: You forgot to flush the server's response

Comment: I think I got it (finally)! It probably has something to do with the fact I'm running the client and server on the same thread right? This way the loop is never accesed

Comment: These are separate programs, they run on separate processes

Comment: btw: nice coding style. Especially the naming of your variables is very nice. I  push things into more methods, but for a newbie, really nice code!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:
I'm stupid.

I accidentally let both the client and the server run on the same thread. I now made `TCPClient` a `Runnable` and everything works as planned.

NOTE:
the `TCPClient.main(null)` does not start a new program/thread, just the same thread, another static function.

Answer (score 0):

You are flushing on the **client** side - but not on the server side!

Simply add a

```
toClient.flush()
```

call on the server side, too!